# Female lead keeps getting killed over and over, snaps and starts a killing spree

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I’m looking for a manhwa that’s about a female lead that keeps getting killed over and over and being sent back to the same point in time. After hundreds of times dying and trying every possible way to get out of the cycle, she finally snaps and starts killing off the people around her.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Resetting Lady](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/novsx9p/resetting-lady)***...?

> Karen Heyer thought that a happy ending with the male lead, Raymond Sayerteth, would help her escape the romance novel she had entered. Unfortunately, fate had other plans. Karen soon discovers that regardless of how the story ends, she always dies tragically and returns to when she was 17. **After being forced to relive the story for 117 years, Karen's sanity finally reaches a breaking point...as she decides to change her destiny by killing everyone who has wronged her.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Very much

Comment: @Blue Sun - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.